# SQL query using GROUP BY on an expression doesn't retrieve all entries

Tags: sql, timestamp

I recently took over some work form another developer and am trying to understand why a specific sql query does not work for certain timestamps, more specifically timestamps on the same date, the sql query is:

```
select FROM_UNIXTIME(order_time,'%Y.%m.%D') as order_time,
       order_time as timealias
  from orders
  where order.id ='.$user->id.'
  group by FROM_UNIXTIME(order_time,'%Y.%m.%D')
  order by timealias desc
```

The idea is that the orders are grouped by date for the user to view, if the dates are on different days.

This works fine:

```
03/08/2012, 15:10:30 (Unix Timestamp: 1344006630)
04/08/2012, 12:10:30 (Unix Timestamp: 1344082230)
```

However, if they are on the same day but at different times, then it displays the first order in the table but the second.

```
03/08/2012, 15:10:30 (Unix Timestamp: 1344006630)
03/08/2012, 17:30:25 (Unix Timestamp: 1344015025)
```

My theory is that it does not recognise the second entry's date as a match to the first entry's, but since that date is used already it breaks, or something to that effect. But considering DBs aren't my strongpoint, it's a guess.

If anyone knows a proper reason why it behaves like this, I would really appreciate some insight.

Comment: General rule: don't use GROUP BY unless you've got some aggregates (COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, etc) in the query.  Also, MySQL notwithstanding, in general you should list all the non-aggregate columns in the SELECT-list in the GROUP BY clause; most SQL DBMS require it, and it provides determinacy which omitting columns from the GROUP BY clause does not.  There are exceptional circumstances under which it is OK (not to list columns in the GROUP BY clause); they are rarer than the circumstances where it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query contains a GROUP BY on FROM_UNIXTIME.  This is going to pick one "random" row for each FROM_UNIXTIME, which isn't what you want.

If you want to see every timestamp, including duplicates:

```
"select FROM_UNIXTIME(order_time,'%Y.%m.%D') as order_time, order_time as timealias from orders where order.id ='".$user->id."' order by timealias desc"
```

If you want to show the number of order for each FROM_UNIXTIME:

```
"select FROM_UNIXTIME(order_time,'%Y.%m.%D') as order_time, order_time as timealias, COUNT(*) order_cnt from orders where order.id ='".$user->id."' group by 1 order by timealias desc"
```